# Использование одного SearchView в разных Fragmentах

Tags: android, kotlin

в activity_main (Activity) имеется Toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "Введите название альбома"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Как к SearchView, лежащем в нем можно получить доступ из разных Fragmentов?

Необходимо чтобы в 2 fragmentах этот поиск вел себя по разному? 
Т.е если открыт Fragment 1, то он выполняет один метод, а если другой Fragment, то другой.

Answer (score 1):

Управлять своими контролами должен только хозяин. В вашем случае это активити.

Между активити и фрагментами надо определить договор (интерфейс) по которому фрагменты будут запрашивать то или иное поведение, а активити исполнять.

Если активити управляет появлением фрагментов и может однозначно определить какой сейчас фрагмент отображен, то можно просто переключать режимы поведения контрола. Тогда интерфейс акивити <-> фрагмент будет проще.